# unable to create logic to play all files sequentially from listView(playlist). at end of a each song(listview item) song should be played

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my code in which i m choosing the directory/Folder to get all (mp3) files in my listview. after adding files in listview i want to play them automatically one by one from first list item to end. I am trying to use indexes of the listview items in for loop. but logically wrong somewhare. May i missing something. Help will be appriciated. Thanks buddies.

```
    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    directoryChooser.setTitle("Select a Folder for Playlist");
    directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("D:\\Songs"));

    File dir = directoryChooser.showDialog(new Stage());

    playlist.getItems().addAll(dir.listFiles());

       try {



        playlist.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
        lastItemIndex = playlist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

        playlist.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        fileToPlayIndex = playlist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,fileToPlayIndex );


    for(int i=fileToPlayIndex; i<=lastItemIndex; i++ ){



        fileToPlay = playlist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        Media media = new Media(fileToPlay.toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

       mdv.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
       mdv.setPreserveRatio(true);

       mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

       DoubleProperty width = mdv.fitWidthProperty();
       DoubleProperty height = mdv.fitHeightProperty();

       width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mdv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
       height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mdv.sceneProperty(),"Height"));


        // voulume slider 
            volslider();

        // seekslider implementation       
            seekslider();

        mediaPlayer.play();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Media is playing ");


        mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mediaPlayer.stop();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Media Has been ended.");

                playlist.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
                   //getting the changed(next) index of the list view item.
              fileToPlayIndex = playlist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); 

              flag = 1;

                mediaPlayer.dispose();
            }
        });


     }



    } 
       catch (Exception eex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,eex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. What exactly do you mean with "I am trying to use for loop but not working." - what's not working? Do you get an Exception? Please be more specific.

Comment: No, I am not getting exception. but unable to create logic to play all files sequentially from listView(playlist). at the end of a song next listview song should be played.

Comment: i am getting the indexes of the listview items and them try to use their index to play all of them in a for loop.

Comment: Then please write an exact question *in your post* (not as a comment). Where do you need help?

Comment: Thanks. @Alexander but if you understand my question then please help me

Comment: No, I don't. I'm not an Android guy. But in order for people to help you, please add a clear question to your post. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask